# 16.04.3 installer hangs/freezes after "Preparing to install Ubuntu". Alternative installer?

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity

I dd'd 16.04.3 desktop amd64 iso to a 4GB Kingston flash drive from which I booted successfully.

The live session works great, in fact I am writing this question from the live session, but the installer (ubiquity) hangs/freezes after the "Preparing to install Ubuntu" screen where the "Download updates while installing" and "Install third-party software" check boxes are. No matter which/any checkbox is checked, no matter if it is run instead of the live session or from within it, no matter if my other flash drive, onto which I want to install, is plugged in or not. I also tried running ubiquity from terminal with/without gtk_ui parameter, and also with sudo. Same problem.

Specifically if I click continue, then I hear the HDD for a few seconds, I see the loading cursor "forever" and nothing happens. I can close it through GUI, though, no need to `kill -9` it. The rest of the system remains responsive, `top` shows `parted_server` as a CPU demanding process besides firefox. The `parted_server` process exits at least a minute after I close `ubiquity` and the partitions of the HDD reappear on the launcher.

A workaround to be able to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 on my other flash drive would be much appreciated. A command-line or text-mode installer would be just fine.

---

machine: ASUS k50ij

partitions on HDD (none of which I want to modify with the installer):

```
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0  23.5G  0 part unused
├─sda3   8:3    0  20.5G  0 part root (Ubuntu 14.04)
└─sda1   8:1    0   189G  0 part data
```

Comment: Did you check the integrity(sha256sum) of iso before loading it on the usb?

Comment: How you did you solved the problem? @muffle